# How to implement Azure AD in Azure Functions in Java

Tags: java, azure-active-directory

**How to implement Azure AD with Azure Functions in Java**

i found the code in .Net everywere . but i want to configure in java language... Please help me ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This document should meet your needs,you can refer to [this](https://dev.to/425show/secure-apis-with-azure-functions-java-azure-ad-and-ms-graph-49p1).